# mysql AND used twice in a query doesn't work

Tags: mysql

The following query

```
SELECT * FROM workshops 
WHERE workshop_zipcode LIKE '75___' 
  OR workshop_zipcode LIKE '77___' 
  AND workshop_category = 14 
  AND active = 1 
  AND workshop_date >= NOW() 
ORDER BY workshop_date ASC
```

don't generate any errors, and actually work, but with a little problem : this part

```
AND workshop_date >= NOW()
```

don't filter anything, itried to replace the comparative sign with an equal, and the same list is retrieved.

the two first AND works well, but the third don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to parenthesize your `OR` condition Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM workshops 
WHERE (workshop_zipcode LIKE '75___' 
OR workshop_zipcode LIKE '77___')
AND workshop_category = 14 
AND active = 1 
AND workshop_date >= NOW() 
ORDER BY workshop_date ASC
```

Without parenthesis you are in essence calling this:

```
SELECT * FROM workshops 
WHERE workshop_zipcode LIKE '75___' 
OR (workshop_zipcode LIKE '77___'
AND workshop_category = 14 
AND active = 1 
AND workshop_date >= NOW())
ORDER BY workshop_date ASC
```

This is because `AND` is calculated before `OR`.  See this reference

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue with operator precedence.

SQL will evaluate all your AND statements first, and then the OR ones; if you put brackets around them, you might get the results you expect:

```
SELECT * FROM workshops 
WHERE (workshop_zipcode LIKE '75___' 
OR workshop_zipcode LIKE '77___')
AND workshop_category = 14 
AND active = 1 
AND workshop_date >= NOW() 
ORDER BY workshop_date ASC
```

That will check for the workshop zipcodes, and then the rest of your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
SELECT * FROM workshops 
WHERE ( workshop_zipcode LIKE '75___' 
OR workshop_zipcode LIKE '77___' )
AND workshop_category = 14 
AND active = 1 
AND workshop_date >= NOW() 
ORDER BY workshop_date ASC
```